# content (or background) remains when draggin the splitter bar to resize two panels

Tags: c++, winapi, panel, splitter

I have a main window with 3 child: `hwndTocBox` (left panel), `hwndSplitter` and `hwndCanvas` (right panel).
`hwndTocBox` has a child `hwndTreeView`, which is a TreeView control. When I drag `hwndSplitter` to the right (i.e want to make `hwndTocBox` and hence `hwndTreeView` bigger), the content (and background?) of `hwndCanvas` and `hwndSplitter` will remain for a while. (When I drag the splitter to the left, there is no problem at all.)

When `hwndSplitter` is draged, it uses `DeferWindowPos()` to resize and move `hwndTocBox`, `hwndSplitter` and `hwndCanvas`. When `hwndTocBox` is resized, in `WM_SIZE` case of its windows procedure, it resizes `hwndTreeView` (still using `DeferWindowPos()`, since it resizes not only `hwndTreeView` but also others).

I have tried to use `CLIPCHILDREN` and `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` in several places, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Why the contents remain there for a while and erased later?

Could you indicate me how to solve this issue, please.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to repaint the portions of the window that you've resized, otherwise you'll get these strange artifacts. There's a reason they look like smears, because that's almost exactly what they are. A certain portion of the content was painted and appeared on screen normally. Then you resized the window. The portion that had already been painted was not repainted because you didn't invalidate it, but the newly-exposed portion had to be repainted because there was nothing there before.

The fix is simple: add a call to the [`InvalidateRect()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002.aspx) at the bottom of your resizing code to ensure that the portion of the window you're resizing gets redrawn the next time that the window processes a `WM_PAINT` message.

If you want to make sure that a `WM_PAINT` message gets processed immediately (resulting in the immediate redrawing of your window's affected regions), follow up with a call to the [`UpdateWindow()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145167.aspx). But this really shouldn't be necessary. It's much more efficient to postpone all of the redrawing to later when everything is finalized, rather than doing it incrementally. Relatively speaking, repainting a window is an expensive operation.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Although I have to put UpdateWindow after InvalidateRect. I think this is because without doing this, the paintings occur later, and before the paintings, I see the dirty region. By the way, I have to do the samething (InvalidateRect and UpdateWindow) for all theses handles. I think this is not an efficient way. Is there any analogy as DefWindowPos for painting several child windows at the same time? (I found that I can use Invalidate(hwndparent, NULL, ...) to do this)

Comment: @user: Yes, you can call `InvalidateRect` and pass `NULL` for the second parameter to indicate that the entire window should be redrawn. And you only need to call `UpdateWindow` if you want to make sure that the screen gets redrawn immediately. If you want it to repaint, for example, *as the user is dragging the mouse*, you will need to call `UpdateWindow`. But that might hurt performance, depending on the power of the user's computer. You'll have to test to see whether it's worth it. That's why lots of apps just drag an outline of the divider—you only have to repaint once that way.